# How to extract only the english words from the list?

Tags: python, regex, string, nlp

I tried to extract only the English words from the following list:

```
l = ['0', 'b', 'x14', 'x00', 'x1fP', 'xe0O', 'xd0', 'xea', 'i', 'x10', 'xa2', 'xd8', 'x08', 'x00', '00', 'x9d', 'x14', 'x00', 'x80', 'xcc', 'xbf', 'xb4', 'xdbLB', 'xb0', 'x7f', 'xe9', 'x9a', 'x87', 'xc6AZ', 'x005', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00yR', 'G', 'x10', 'x00', 'xdc', 'x05', 'xde', 'x05', 'xe2', 'x05', 'xe8', 'x05', 'xdb', 'x05', 'xea', 'x05', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 't', 'x00', 'x04', 'x00', 'xef', 'xbeyRnDyR', 'G', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'xe5E', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'xfb', 'x05', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'xe2', 'x0e', 'x00', 'xdc', 'x05', 'xde', 'x05', 'xe2', 'x05', 'xe8', 'x05', 'xdb', 'x05', 'xea', 'x05', 'x00', 'x00', 'x1c', 'x00', 'x80', 'x001', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00yR', 'G', 'x10', 'x00VBS', '', '', 'x00', 'x00', 't', 'x00', 'x04', 'x00', 'xef', 'xbeyR', 'GyR', 'G', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x9e', 'xa5', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00K', 'x02', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'xe2', 'x0e', 'x00V', 'x00B', 'x00S', 'x00', 'x00R', 'x00a', 'x00n', 'x00s', 'x00o', 'x00m', 'x00w', 'x00a', 'x00r', 'x00e', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00d', 'x00o', 'x00n', 'x00e', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x80', 'x001', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00yRmG', 'x10', 'x00VBS', '', '', 'x00', 'x00', 't', 'x00', 'x04', 'x00', 'xef', 'xbeyR', 'GyRmG', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'xb6', 'xba', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'xa4', 'x01', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x98w', 'x00V', 'x00B', 'x00S', 'x00', 'x00R', 'x00a', 'x00n', 'x00s', 'x00o', 'x00m', 'x00w', 'x00a', 'x00r', 'x00e', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00d', 'x00o', 'x00n', 'x00e', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'xa4', 'x002', 'x00c', 'xf1', 'x02', 'x00oRjX', 'Test', 'For', 'SO', 'PDF', 'pdf', 'x00t', 'x00', 't', 'x00', 'x04', 'x00', 'xef', 'xbeyR', 'GyR', 'G', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'xcf', 'xbc', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00z', 'x04', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'xd23', 'x98', 'x00D', 'x00e', 'x00f', 'x00e', 'x00n', 'x00s', 'x00e', 'x00', 'x00R', 'x00u', 'x00l', 'x00e', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00V', 'x00B', 'x00S', 'x00', 'x00R', 'x00a', 'x00n', 'x00s', 'x00o', 'x00m', 'x00w', 'x00a', 'x00r', 'x00e', 'x00', 'x00p', 'x00d', 'x00f', 'x00', 'x00', 'x000', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', '3']
```

From this list, the words I need are `["Test", "For", "SO", "PDF"]`.

I tried the following:

```
for i in range(num_of_values):
    values = EnumValue(key, i)
    res = re.findall(r'\w+', str(values))
    print(res)
```

Did anyone manage to extract the words?

Comment: How exactly do you plan on determining if something is an English word? Do you have a data source to which you can compare your strings & determine if they are in fact English words?

Comment: did you try any library? PyEnchant, NLTK? take a look on ntlk.corpus and it word list, then you can test each word individually (if exists in the nltk wordlist)..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get it working to some extent with [`pyenchant` library](https://pypi.org/project/pyenchant/) that allows checking if a word is a valid word in a given language. Before checking linguistic validity, you need to check if

- the word is not empty and is more than one char long
- the word consists of letters only.

So, in Python, you need to install the `pyenchant` library first (`pip install pyenchant` in the terminal/console), and then

```py
import enchant
l = ['0', 'b', 'x14', 'x00', 'x1fP', 'xe0O', 'xd0', 'xea', 'i', 'x10', 'xa2', 'xd8', 'x08', 'x00', '00', 'x9d', 'x14', 'x00', 'x80', 'xcc', 'xbf', 'xb4', 'xdbLB', 'xb0', 'x7f', 'xe9', 'x9a', 'x87', 'xc6AZ', 'x005', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00yR', 'G', 'x10', 'x00', 'xdc', 'x05', 'xde', 'x05', 'xe2', 'x05', 'xe8', 'x05', 'xdb', 'x05', 'xea', 'x05', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 't', 'x00', 'x04', 'x00', 'xef', 'xbeyRnDyR', 'G', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'xe5E', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'xfb', 'x05', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'xe2', 'x0e', 'x00', 'xdc', 'x05', 'xde', 'x05', 'xe2', 'x05', 'xe8', 'x05', 'xdb', 'x05', 'xea', 'x05', 'x00', 'x00', 'x1c', 'x00', 'x80', 'x001', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00yR', 'G', 'x10', 'x00VBS', '', '', 'x00', 'x00', 't', 'x00', 'x04', 'x00', 'xef', 'xbeyR', 'GyR', 'G', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x9e', 'xa5', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00K', 'x02', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'xe2', 'x0e', 'x00V', 'x00B', 'x00S', 'x00', 'x00R', 'x00a', 'x00n', 'x00s', 'x00o', 'x00m', 'x00w', 'x00a', 'x00r', 'x00e', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00d', 'x00o', 'x00n', 'x00e', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x80', 'x001', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00yRmG', 'x10', 'x00VBS', '', '', 'x00', 'x00', 't', 'x00', 'x04', 'x00', 'xef', 'xbeyR', 'GyRmG', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'xb6', 'xba', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'xa4', 'x01', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x98w', 'x00V', 'x00B', 'x00S', 'x00', 'x00R', 'x00a', 'x00n', 'x00s', 'x00o', 'x00m', 'x00w', 'x00a', 'x00r', 'x00e', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00d', 'x00o', 'x00n', 'x00e', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'xa4', 'x002', 'x00c', 'xf1', 'x02', 'x00oRjX', 'Test', 'For', 'SO', 'PDF', 'pdf', 'x00t', 'x00', 't', 'x00', 'x04', 'x00', 'xef', 'xbeyR', 'GyR', 'G', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'xcf', 'xbc', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00z', 'x04', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'xd23', 'x98', 'x00D', 'x00e', 'x00f', 'x00e', 'x00n', 'x00s', 'x00e', 'x00', 'x00R', 'x00u', 'x00l', 'x00e', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00V', 'x00B', 'x00S', 'x00', 'x00R', 'x00a', 'x00n', 'x00s', 'x00o', 'x00m', 'x00w', 'x00a', 'x00r', 'x00e', 'x00', 'x00p', 'x00d', 'x00f', 'x00', 'x00', 'x000', 'x00', 'x00', 'x00', '3']
d = enchant.Dict("en_US") 
output = [el for el in l if len(el)>1 and el.isalpha() and d.check(el)]
>>> output
# => ['Test', 'For', 'SO', 'PDF']
```

Comment: @Jan I excuded one letter words as the expected output also has none. It is possible to add any exceptions for that ``len(el)>1` rule. The point is using `pyenchant` library

Comment: Can you please describe what are the variables: 'el' and 'd'?

Comment: @PyberGeek`el` is an element in the `l` list (your input). `d` is the `d = enchant.Dict("en_US")`, I forgot to add this line to the code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

if you know what you want to search , just search .

```
# 'a' is your data list 

search=["Test", "For", "SO", "PDF", "pdf"]

for s in search:
    print(a.index(s))
```

output index of the words you search in your list:

```
253
254
255
256
257
```

But if you want to search all the english words you need a dictonary , then search every english word.

```
# This find all the occurrences for every words in the list 'a' 

#search is your list with words to search 

for s in search:
    indeces = [i for i, x in enumerate(a) if x == s]
    print(s,indeces)
```

output:

```
Test [253]
For [254]
SO [255]
PDF [256]
pdf [257]
```

Answer (score 0):

seems you know in advance what to extract from the list so I give you some ideas:

```
# Example 1: Search using a loop and create a new list
list_2 = []
for element in list_1:
    if 'pdf' in element:
            list_2.append(element)
            print('the element is in the list and was added to list_2 ')
    
# Example 2: If you know in advance what to extract use list comprehension
list_0 = ['Test', 'For', 'SO', 'PDF', 'pdf']
for elements in list_0: 
    if elements in list_1:
        print(elements)

# Checking if something is inside the list
for elements in list_1:
    if 'Test' in elements:
        print('The element is in the list')
        
# Return the element number in the list
index = list_1.index('Test')
print(index)
```

Let me know if this work for you.