# efficient way to extract only words also found in english dictionary from a mix of symbols, numbers and meaningless sequences

Tags: nlp

Examples of input are error messages and logs. I have read this thread

[How to extract only the english words from the list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66931801/how-to-extract-only-the-english-words-from-the-list)

I can also think of using "if x in "

Speed is very important for this task. Any clever idea to make it faster?